# how to read a file string by string in python and after reading assign to list

Tags: python

As for example:
creating a file `bit0.txt`
inside the file content is:

```
Port   Command        ExpectedResult           Comments

A        C            Ack Resp:\x43\x80   ;  All flags bit of port A clear
B        C            Ack Resp:\x43\x80   ;  All flags bit of port B clear
A     S001002         Ack Resp:\x06\x53   ;  S command Change output 1
A        C            Ack Resp:\x43\x81   ;  port A bit 0 set
B        C            Ack Resp:\x43\x81   ;  port B bit 0 set
A        Q            Ack Resp:\x51\x31   ;  read change queue on port A
A        C            Ack Resp:\x43\x80   ;  port A bit 0 clear
B        C            Ack Resp:\x43\x81   ;  port B bit 0 set
B        Q            Ack Resp:\x51\x31   ;  read change queue on port B
A        C            Ack Resp:\x43\x80   ;  port A bit 0 clear
B        C            Ack Resp:\x43\x80   ;  port B bit 0 clear
```

Now i have to read this file through another python program and output should come like this:

After reading file, API should return :

```
result = [['A','C', 'Ack Resp:\x43\x80'],
          ['B','C', 'Ack Resp:\x43\x80'],
          ['A','S001002', 'Ack Resp:\x06\x53'],
          ...............till end of file ]
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) Show some of your code. And look around SO, there are many discussions on this.

Comment: [`import csv`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/csv.html?highlight=csv#csv)...

Answer (score 0):

You can `import csv` or write code by youself.
There is a example:

```
result = []
with open(bit0.txt) as f:
    for index, l in enumerate(f):
        if index > 1:
            result.append((l.split(';')[0]).split())
```

The `result` argument is you want

Or can define a `function` like this:

```
def helper(filename):
    result = []
    with open(filename) as f:
        for index, l in enumerate(f):
            if index > 1:
                result.append((l.split(';')[0]).split())
    return result

print helper(bit0.txt)
```

The output is

```
[['A','C', 'Ack Resp:\x43\x80'],
      ['B','C', 'Ack Resp:\x43\x80'],
      ['A','S001002', 'Ack Resp:\x06\x53'],
      ...............till end of file ]
```